# Vue.js weird behavior from watcher with a loading state

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I'm using Vue.js (2) I have three elements:

- 1: A template with the root wired via v-if to--
- 2: A loading computed property, and this "loading" is watched by--
- 3: A watcher.

  ```
  computed: {

      loading() {
          return this.$store.state.myCoolObject.loading
      },

  }

  watch: {

      loading(newVal, oldVal) {

          if(newVal == false) {
              console.log(this.$el)
          }

      },
  }


  <template>
      <div v-if="!loading">
          Life, uh, finds a way.
      </div>
  </template>
  ```

You see this really does almost nothing. But when this runs in my project almost all of the elements disappear. Has anyone ever encountered something like this before. I just hates it when I do anything with "this" or "this.$el"

Comment: Is the value you use in loading() a vue property?

Comment: this.$store.state.myCoolObject.loading is a vuex state

Comment: @CodeOwl what do you mean by _"almost all of the elements disappear"_ ?

Comment: I've looked into this more and what is happening is that something is going wrong with vuex and all of the v-if statements that depend on the state tree are reading as false, causing the component to be scrubbed from the dom.